# Visual fox Pro 9. Combo box usage for address

Tags: visual-foxpro

How can i create 2 combo box that is linked for address usage.

I have a table named Places with 2 fields. Region and city.

The first combo box drops down the list of regions and when i picked one
the next combo box results the cities in that regions.

how do i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RowSourceType=3 (SQL) for both. RoWSource properties then look like:

```
select Region, RegionID from Regions order by Region into cursor crsRegions

select City, CityId from Cities where RegionId = crsRegions.RegionId order by City into cursor crsCities
```

In valid or InteractiveChange of region combo call require of cities combo ( cmbCities.Requery() ).

That is it. You get the selected values (or any field's value you need) using the alias.field syntax like crsCities.cityId.

Comment: Thanks @cetin basoz